# В каком предложении запятая поставлена ошибочно?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сказуемые

***Безветрие, и все небо залито ровной синевой.***

***Надвигались темные дождевые тучи, и потягивало влагой.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни в каком. Оба оформлены пунктуационно верно.

*Безветрие, и все небо залито ровной синевой.*
Сложносочинённое, состоит из односоставного назывного и двусоставного. Общего члена нет.

*Надвигались темные дождевые тучи, и потягивало влагой.*
Сложносочинённое , состоит из двусоставного и односоставного безличного.

Пример: ***С востока** надвигались темные дождевые тучи и потягивало влагой.*
Вот если бы было так, тогда запятой бы не было, потому что есть общий член.

Comment: Здесь следующие варианты вопроса. Мне кажется правильным наличие запятых.Пожалуйста объясните в чем моя ошибка.      1) Мелькнет в бурьяне булыжник , или перебежит дорогу заяц.   2) В декабре мороз нарастает , и день становится совсем коротким.   3) Небо снова все покрылось тучами , и посыпался дождь.

Comment: 2) В декабре мороз нарастает и день становится совсем коротким. -запятой нет, потому что есть общий член В ДЕКАБРЕ.